# how can replace Thread.sleep() with RXJava

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, thread-sleep

when I use `Thread.sleep()` for the delay in my app I get crash `InterruptedException`.

I have to use `Thread.sleep()` because I send Command to hardware and need to get data after 1 second.

can I use RX java for this problem? or other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can replace `Thread.sleep()` in **RX java** using `delay` in Observable. Here how to do it:

```
Observable.delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

using `interval` will do thing infinite time at the `interval` of provided time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `interval` in RxJava

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```